# exclude directories mv unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command-line-interface

The command below moves every hidden/normal file ending with *string without . or _ before it.

```
 mv {.,}*[!._]string /destination
```

How can I also exclude moving all directories in the above command?

Comment: You are better off with `find`.

Comment: @squiguy How would I convert this to find?

Comment: What do you want exclude exactly?

Comment: Exactly what I said in the question.  I want to move all things named the {.,}*[!._]string excluding all directories.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
find /WHERE/TO/FIND -name '*STRING' \( ! -name '*_STRING' -o ! -name '*.STRING' \) -type f -exec mv \{\} /WHERE/TO/MOVE \;
```

Note, if you want to move every file from only the `/WHERE/TO/FIND` directory, you should add `-maxdepth 1` (after e.g. the `-type f` part).

Comment: Will this also work with hidden files?

Comment: Definitely. Find does that by default.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
for file in {.,}*[!._]string; do test -f "$file" && mv "$file" /destination; done
```

In what shell does the `[!._]` glob actually work when used with `{.,}`?  You would probably be better off avoiding the `{}` notation and do:

```
for file in .*[!._]string *[!._]string; do ... ; done
```